# get_posts inside cron

Tags: get-posts, cron, wp-cron

**Edited to rewrite my question**

I'll try to be as clear as possible, as I need to get this resolved quickly.

I disabled WordPress' cron, and added a real cron job on my server to call wp-cron.php every day. The function i'm calling is not working, however.

Code execution seems to stop at `get_posts`, same thing if I try using the `WP_Query` class. No error message, and any code after just doesn't execute.

When I don't add `numberposts`, it does however give me 5 posts, which is the default value for numberposts.

Sample :

```
 $posts = get_posts( array(
     'post_type'    => 'post-type',
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'tax_query'    => array(
           array(
                'taxonomy'  =>  'tax',
                'field'     =>  'slug',
                'terms' =>  'term-slug'
           )
      )
 ));
```

**More Info**

- The post type and the taxonomy are created in my plugin file on the
  `init` hook.
- The function works fine when being executed from a PHP page, like my plugin's setting page.
- I tried hooking my function in `wp_ajax_nopriv`, and calling `admin-ajax.php?action=the-action` from my server cron, but with the exact same result.
- I haven't tried keeping WP's cron, because the function takes a long time to execute, and you need a visitor launch it by visiting the site.

Please reply with any questions / code request if more information is required.

**Edit - My loop**

```
 set_time_limit( 1800 );

 $stores = get_option( 'stores' );

 foreach( $stores as $store_name => $store )
 {

      $ctime = 0;
      $filename = '';
      $xml_path = '';

      $dir = dir( $store );

      while( false !== ( $entry = $dir->read() ) )
      {

           $info = pathinfo( $entry );

           $ext = strtolower( $info['extension'] );

           $filepath = "{$store}/{$entry}";

           if( is_file( $filepath ) && $ext == 'xml' && filectime( $filepath ) > $ctime )
           {

                $ctime = filectime( $filepath );

                $filename = $entry;

                $xml_path = $filepath;

           }

      }

      if( file_exists( $xml_path ) && is_file( $xml_path ) )
      {

           //
           //Delete products first
           //
           $posts = get_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'produit-xml',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                     array(
                          'taxonomy'    =>  'succursale',
                          'field'       =>  'slug',
                          'terms'       =>  $store_name
                     )
                )
           ));

           foreach( $posts as $post )
           {

                $image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nom_photo', true );

                if( $image )
                {

                     $fullpath = ABSPATH . get_option( $store_name . '-image-path' );

                     $fullpath .= '/resized/' . $image;

                     @unlink( $fullpath );

                }

                wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true );

           }

           //
           //Insert operations follow....
           //

      }

 }
```

Comment: What about when WP_DEBUG is activated? Also can we see your loop?

Comment: How many posts are you trying to actually pull out here? Because I bet you're running out of PHP memory when you try to get them all using -1.

Comment: @TomJNowell I've added part of my loop, it's quite long so I added the problematic part. I'll try it out with WP_DEBUG.

Comment: @Otto I have 13 taxonomy terms, each holding about 1000 to 2000 posts.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it. Bump your PHP memory_limit way up, like to 256M or so, and see if it works then.

Comment: Also that loop is not your posts loop, it's calling on an option, if the file's large, something like pastebin.com might be best

Comment: @TomJNowell Yeah that's because there is no WordPress loop, everything after the code I pasted is simply going over an xml file and inserting posts.

Comment: Then why use `get_posts`?

Comment: Well I am running a `foreach` on the posts in my code above if you scroll down. I'm using it because I need to fetch all posts of a specified taxonomy term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you do get_posts or WP_Query or anything like that, it's important to remember that the code is actually getting all of the Posts at once, and loading them from the database into memory. If you run out of memory, then your process will simply die with an error. Attempting to get very large numbers of posts at once will cause this quite often.

Turn on PHP's display_errors. You'll likely see an out of memory error.

Next, bump up the PHP memory_limit setting to 128M or 256M and see if you now have enough memory to do it.

Alternately, rewrite your get_posts to use pagination. Get them 100 at a time or something along those lines. Then you're not trying to pull 1000s of posts into memory all at once.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, definately getting me on the right track. Increasing my limit hasn't worked, but fetching 500 at a time sure got more done than previously.

Comment: I noticed in your Loop that you're only actually using the ID numbers of the posts. Try setting the 'fields' parameter to 'ids'. This will make the query only get the IDs of the posts and not all the rest of the associated content and such that you don't need. Could be loads faster and save a bunch of memory.

Comment: You're right, I just found out about the `fields` parameter, didn't see it in the documentation. Thanks